# How to create valid image from RGB pixel values using java

Tags: java, arrays, image, image-processing

I have a 2D array which contains the RGB values. I need to create a valid image from these pixel values and save it. I have given the 2D array below. I wanted to implement this part in my project, so please help me with this. Thank you.

```
         int[] pixels = new int[imageSize * 3];
         int k = 0;
         for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
         {
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            {
                if(k<imageSize*3)
               {
                    pixels[k] = r[i][j];
                    pixels[k+1] = g[i][j];
                    pixels[k+2] = b[i][j];
                }
               k = k+3;
            }
         }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) of type [`BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_RGB). This type represents a color as an `int` where:

- 3rd byte (16-23) is red,
- 2nd byte (8-15) is green and
- 1st byte (7-0) is blue.

You can get the pixel `RGB` value as follows:

```
int rgb = red;
rgb = (rgb << 8) + green; 
rgb = (rgb << 8) + blue;
```

Example ([Ideone full example code](http://ideone.com/UmEj5W)):

```
  BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB); 

  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
     for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        int rgb = r[y][x];
        rgb = (rgb << 8) + g[y][x]; 
        rgb = (rgb << 8) + b[y][x];
        image.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
     }
  }

  File outputFile = new File("/output.bmp");
  ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", outputFile);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i have seen similar answers along with a raster class along with your example, and I got confused as i am unaware of that class usage. But your answer is working even without raster class. Thanks a lot.